# Can't install APK when running my application

Tags: android

I can't install my app's APK when trying to run my application. My application's logs are shown on my phone through USB debug, but there is no response when I click on the install button. I am able to click the cancel button instead.

Maybe it has something to do with my adb.exe file? previously my adb file was deleted by Avast so i had to manually download it.

android manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NumbersActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_numbers"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FamilyActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_family"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ColorsActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_colors"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PhrasesActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_phrases"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

> event log
>
> 10:27 PM   Gradle sync started
>
> 10:27 PM   Project setup started
>
> 10:28 PM   Gradle sync finished in 34s 30ms (from cached state)
>
> 10:39 PM   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 10:39 PM   * daemon started successfully
>
> 10:40 PM   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 10:42 PM   Gradle build finished in 1m 41s 468ms

the following is the warning

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

#### the screenshot of the app

[image: the screenshot of the app is here]

Comment: Turn off filter and it's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What phone are you using? It maybe some problem with the phone custom rom. Try to check if there is any setting related to adb install inside the developer options.

Comment: Huawei honor 6, i still can't find any solution

Comment: Calm down and feel relax. It might not be your fault. I use Huawei phone as development device before and I gave up. Huawei devices always come up with strange problem which you will never find on the other phone. Maybe you can try it on some other phone and see.  @johncool

Comment: previously i was using the same phone for USB debug without any problem, but after i manual download the adb file this issue occurred.

Comment: now i use other device debug and it work fine, something wrong with my Huawei device setting i guess

Comment: I really think this is a device related issue, Huawei phone may not be the best option for android debug device. They also can change some system setting after system update, Huawei makes lots of customize for their phone.

Answer (score 0):

On your settings you need to set "allow installation of apps from unknown sources" under security settings.